# Memory leak in XNA game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, xna

I have a small part of a game which basically shows a page from a book. The Update method does not do anything and the Draw method is as follows:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = ScreenManager.SpriteBatch;

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(background.Image, background.Bounds, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, name, new Vector2(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - font.MeasureString(name).X / 2, 100), Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, currentPage.PageText, new Vector2(currentPage.TextArea.X, currentPage.TextArea.Y), Color.Black);
    if (currentPageNumber != 1)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(next.Image, previous.Bounds, null, Color.White, 0.0F, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 0.0F);
    }
    if (currentPageNumber != noOfPages)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(next.Image, next.Bounds, Color.White);
    }
    DrawEmptyRectangle(spriteBatch, 3F, Color.Black, new Rectangle(back.Bounds.X - 1, back.Bounds.Y - 1, back.Bounds.Width + 1, back.Bounds.Height + 1));
    DrawEmptyRectangle(spriteBatch, 3F, Color.Black, new Rectangle(play.Bounds.X - 1, play.Bounds.Y - 1, play.Bounds.Width + 1, play.Bounds.Height + 1));
    DrawCenteredText(spriteBatch, font, BACK_TEXT, back.Bounds, Color.Black);
    DrawCenteredText(spriteBatch, font, PLAY_TEXT, play.Bounds, Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.End();
}

public void DrawCenteredText(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont font, string text, Rectangle toCenterIn, Color textColor)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text, new Vector2(toCenterIn.X + toCenterIn.Width / 2 - font.MeasureString(text).X / 2, toCenterIn.Y + toCenterIn.Height / 2 - font.MeasureString(text).Y / 2), textColor);
}

public void DrawEmptyRectangle(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float width, Color color, Rectangle rectangle)
{
    Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top);
    Vector2 bottomLeft = new Vector2(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom);
    Vector2 topRight = new Vector2(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Top);
    Vector2 bottomRight = new Vector2(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom);

    _2DLine.Draw(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch, width, color, topLeft, topRight);
    _2DLine.Draw(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch, width, color, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
    _2DLine.Draw(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch, width, color, topLeft, new Vector2(bottomLeft.X, bottomLeft.Y + width));
    _2DLine.Draw(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch, width, color, topRight, bottomRight);
}
```

This is the _2DLine.Draw method:

```
public static void Draw(GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice, SpriteBatch batch, float width, Color color, Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2)
{
    Texture2D blank = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
    blank.SetData(new[] { Color.White });

    float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(point2.Y - point1.Y, point2.X - point1.X);
    float length = Vector2.Distance(point1, point2);

    batch.Draw(blank, point1, null, color, angle, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(length, width), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

The problem is that the longer I leave the program running the more memory it allocates.

Comment: Are you using Code Analysis? The CA2000 rule will help point out instances of disposable objects it cannot see been disposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your leak is here:

```
Texture2D blank = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
```

You shouldn't allocate textures every frame like this. Create one and re-use it. When you're done with it, call its Dispose() method so it can release its underlying Direct3D resource.

Comment: so I should call its Dispose() right after every draw? I didn't understand exactly where the call should be. Also, I have never called Dispose() when developing in general. I am assuming ContentManager.Unload() does this automatically, right?

Comment: You *could* new up a Texture2D and Dispose() it on each frame, but that would be terrible for performance. Instead, create a Texture2D once (at initialization), and re-use it on each frame. Call Dispose() when you know won't be drawing anymore with it.

The ContentManager automatically disposes objects it manages, i.e. objects you obtain through ContentManager.Load<>. When you new up objects yourself like you're doing here, you're responsible for managing their lifetime.